# Which module will allow me to see the two buttons "Customize this page" and "Change the layout"?

Tags: panels, distributions

When I use the Drupal distribution Openchruch, and I view a page as an administrator. There are two buttons in bottom:
**customize this page** 
and 
**change the layout**

### Which module will let these two buttons appear?

Answer (score 2):

Panels and "Panels In-Place Editor" (sub-module of panels)

Comment: but after I active Panels In-Place Editor,I failed to see the two buttons. if is there something  I miss?

Comment: I resolved it . in Renderer ,need to select In-Place Editor instead of standard

Comment: vote up and accept the answer if you think it is correct